# Issue with developing a multi-module Go workspace

Tags: go, go-modules, go-packages

My folder structure looks something like this... (say my git repo name is demorepo)

```
demorepo
|--directory1
   |-- (no go.mod at this level)
   |--module1
      |--package1 --------->--------------->--------------------->----|
      |--go.mod (github.com/demorepo/directory1/module1)              |
      |--go.sum                                                       |
   |--module2                                                         |
   |--module3                                                         |
|--directory2                                                         |
  |-- (no go.mod at this level)                                       |
  |--newmodule ------<------------<------------------<----------------|
```

Now, I want to use a function defined in "package1" in my "newmodule"

When I hit
go get <repo_address>/directort1/module1/package1 at "new_module"
it says ....

```
github.com/<repo>@upgrade found (v0.0.0-20211215055943-92e412ad4a12), but does not contain package github.com/<repo>/directory1/module1/package1
```

Comment: In your `go.mod` file put `package1 v0.0.1` in `require` block. Later bottom of that file `replace package1 v0.0.1 => ./full_path_of/package1`. Now you should be able to call function in `newmodule`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [proposal for a Go Workspace File](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/45713) for Go 1.18 which should simplify this task.

Meanwhile, you can use the [`replace` directive](https://go.dev/ref/mod#go-mod-file-replace) in your `go.mod` file to refer to a module located on a local filesystem.

**`demorepo/directory1/module1/go.mod`**:

```
module github.com/<repo>/directory1/module1
```

**`demorepo/directory2/newmodule/go.mod`**:

```
module github.com/<repo>/directory2/newmodule

replace github.com/<repo>/directory1/module1 => ../../directory1/module1
```

Now you can `import github.com/<repo>/directory1/module1/package1` in `newmodule` normally and it'll refer to the local `module1`.

You might not want the `replace` directive in the `go.mod` file itself, and instead make a copy of it e.g. `go.local.mod` and use it when building your project: `go build -modfile go.local.mod .` (can also add `go.local.mod` to `.gitignore`).

Comment: At least for go 1.20, filename must end with .mod , so let the filename be: go.local.mod, also, to keep the file updated with latest sources when running go mod tidy, use go mod tidy -modfile go.local.mod

Answer (score 0):

**Approach :**

If you want to use `module1` inside `newModule` then you should make one new `repo` for `module1` put your logic there push it in `github`. please make sure you should use appropriate `version` for the library.

`import` it as a `library` and it will work.

Also refer the official docs of module dependency and also check root level dependency.

Official docs : https://go.dev/blog/using-go-modules

Comment: This could be a way.. The directories were indeed 2 seperate git repos earlier.. But, now I am supposed to merge those git repos and thats how this question came into picture